# Keeping reactivity while doing http request into another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this app structure

```
<header-bar></header-bar>    

<bag :bag="bag"></bag>

<!--Main Section-->
<section class="MainSection">

    <div class="MainSection__wrap">
        <router-view 
            is="view" 
            transition="fade" 
            transition-mode="out-in"
            keep-alive
        >
        </router-view>
    </div>

</section>
```

As you see there are 2 components and router view.

Router view contain the products listed from API, and those products could be added to the bag component.

In my products view (part of router view) I have method that add item to the bag - basically making the POST HTTP Request to server

```
addToBag() {
   productService.add(this.item)
      .then(item => {
          console.log('sucess !)
      })
}
```

And this work, but only after reloading, I can see items in the bag.

Dispatching event is thing that could work, but components hierarchy doesn't allow me to use it.

Comment: The data for the bag can be computed data, which will help you get the data from server. Better way in your case may be using web sockets.

Comment: @Deepak thanks for reply.Any example how to achieve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an item server-side. You also need to add the item to the `vm.bag` data. You may want to use `Vuex`. Basically, what you need is access to the same "bag" both from your `bag` component (you already have) **and** from your "productService" or "addToBag" methods.

So, in the component where you declare the `bag` data, you should change:

```
// from
    /* inside component */
    data: function() {
        return {
            bag: []
        }
    }


// to
var state = {
    bag: []
}

    /* inside component */
    data: function() {
        return {
            bag: state.bag
        }
    }
```

Then, you use the same `bag` array in your `addToBag` method:

```
addToBag() {
   productService.add(this.item)
      .then(item => {
          state.bag.push(item)
      })
}
```